# pull data using xmltable and XMLNAMESPACES

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, qxmlquery

I'm trying to pull values from the XML below, stored in `xml_table` as XMLType,  using Oracle SQL.

```
select x.*
from xml_table t  
 , xmltable( XMLNAMESPACES (
  'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS "env",
  'urn:com.workday/bsvc' as "wd"
),  'for $i in //wd:Get_Worker_Costing_Allocations_Response return $i' 
 --,'env:Envelope/env:Body/wd:Get_Worker_Costing_Allocations_Response/wd:Response_Data/wd:Worker_Costing_Allocations_Data'  
     passing t.raw_xml  
     columns Employee_ID number        path 'wd:Response_Data/wd:Worker_Costing_Allocations_Data/wd:Worker_Reference/wd:ID[2]'
            ,Position_ID        varchar2(100) path 'wd:Response_Data/wd:Worker_Costing_Allocations_Data/wd:Position_Reference/wd:ID[2]'
            --,start_Date     date path   'wd:Response_Data/wd:Worker_Costing_Allocations_Data/wd:Worker_Costing_Allocation_Interval_Data/wd:Start_Date' 
   ) x
```

When i tried to get the fund id and other details like `Cost_Center_Reference_ID` could not get from `Worker_Costing_Allocation_Interval_Data`. Ultimately i have to loop through all `Worker_Costing_Allocation_Interval_Data` nodes.

```
select x.*
   from xml_table t  
     , xmltable( XMLNAMESPACES (
      'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS "env",
      'urn:com.workday/bsvc' as "wd"
    ),  'for $i in //wd:Worker_Costing_Allocation_Detail_Data return $i' 
     --,'env:Envelope/env:Body/wd:Get_Worker_Costing_Allocations_Response/wd:Response_Data/wd:Worker_Costing_Allocations_Data'  
         passing t.raw_xml  
         columns order_1     varchar2(20) path   'wd:Order'
                 ,fund_id     varchar2(20) path   'wd:Costing_Override_Worktag_Reference/wd:ID[@Fund_ID]' 
       ) x
```

Expected Output:

```
employee_id Position_Id Start_Date  End_Date    Order   Fund_ID Project_ID  Program_ID  Cost_Center_Reference_ID    Custom_Organization_Reference_ID    Distribution_Percent
11111   P11111  7/1/2018    6/30/2050   a   FD89    PJ122201    PG11130 CC12340     0.4
11111   P11111  7/1/2018    6/30/2050   b   FD89    PJ122201    PG11130 CC1234      0.6
11111   P11111  7/1/2017    6/30/2018   a   FD30    PJ000001    PG00003 CC0565  UD000004    1
11111   P11111  1/1/2017    6/30/2017   a   FD30    PJ000001    PG00003 CC0565  UD000004    1
```

Below is the raw XML inserted to `xml_table`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <env:Body>
        <wd:Get_Worker_Costing_Allocations_Response xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc" wd:version="v15">
            <wd:Request_Criteria>
                <wd:Costing_Override_Criteria>
                    <wd:Worker_Reference wd:Descriptor="First, Last">
                        <wd:ID wd:type="WID">WID1234</wd:ID>
                        <wd:ID wd:type="Employee_ID">11111</wd:ID>
                    </wd:Worker_Reference>
                </wd:Costing_Override_Criteria>
            </wd:Request_Criteria>
            <wd:Response_Group>
                <wd:Exclude_Allocation_Detail_Data>0</wd:Exclude_Allocation_Detail_Data>
            </wd:Response_Group>
            <wd:Response_Results>
                <wd:Total_Results>1</wd:Total_Results>
                <wd:Total_Pages>1</wd:Total_Pages>
                <wd:Page_Results>1</wd:Page_Results>
                <wd:Page>1</wd:Page>
            </wd:Response_Results>
            <wd:Response_Data>
                <wd:Worker_Costing_Allocations_Data>
                    <wd:Worker_Reference wd:Descriptor="First, Last">
                        <wd:ID wd:type="WID">WID1234</wd:ID>
                        <wd:ID wd:type="Employee_ID">11111</wd:ID>
                    </wd:Worker_Reference>
                    <wd:Position_Reference wd:Descriptor="P11111 Student - First, Last.">
                        <wd:ID wd:type="WID">WID2345</wd:ID>
                        <wd:ID wd:type="Position_ID">P11111</wd:ID>
                    </wd:Position_Reference>
                    <wd:Worker_Costing_Allocation_Interval_Data>
                        <wd:Costing_Override_ID>COSTING_OVERRIDE-X-ZZZZ</wd:Costing_Override_ID>
                        <wd:Start_Date>2018-07-01-07:00</wd:Start_Date>
                        <wd:End_Date>2050-06-30-07:00</wd:End_Date>
                        <wd:Worker_Costing_Allocation_Detail_Data>
                            <wd:Order>a</wd:Order>
                            <wd:Costing_Override_Worktag_Reference wd:Descriptor="FD89 XXXXX YYYYY">
                                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">WIDXXXXX</wd:ID>
                                <wd:ID wd:type="Fund_ID">FD89</wd:ID>
                            </wd:Costing_Override_Worktag_Reference>
                            <wd:Costing_Override_Worktag_Reference wd:Descriptor="PJ122201 XXXXX YYYYY">
                                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">d18edc6167911037c23bcdd377765bf3</wd:ID>
                                <wd:ID wd:type="Project_ID">PJ122201</wd:ID>
                            </wd:Costing_Override_Worktag_Reference>
                            <wd:Costing_Override_Worktag_Reference wd:Descriptor="PG11130 XXXXX YYYYY">
                                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">d18edc61679110372db25f84888138fc</wd:ID>
                                <wd:ID wd:type="Program_ID">PG11130</wd:ID>
                            </wd:Costing_Override_Worktag_Reference>
                            <wd:Costing_Override_Worktag_Reference wd:Descriptor="CC12340 XXXXX YYYYY">
                                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">d18edc61679110376fe5ad0c91c3805f</wd:ID>
                                <wd:ID wd:type="Organization_Reference_ID">CC12340</wd:ID>
                                <wd:ID wd:type="Cost_Center_Reference_ID">CC12340</wd:ID>
                            </wd:Costing_Override_Worktag_Reference>
                            <wd:Distribution_Percent>0.4</wd:Distribution_Percent>
                        </wd:Worker_Costing_Allocation_Detail_Data>
                        <wd:Worker_Costing_Allocation_Detail_Data>
                            <wd:Order>b</wd:Order>
                            <wd:Costing_Override_Worktag_Reference wd:Descriptor="CC1234 XXXXX YYYYY">
                                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">WIDXXXXX</wd:ID>
                                <wd:ID wd:type="Organization_Reference_ID">CC1234</wd:ID>
                                <wd:ID wd:type="Cost_Center_Reference_ID">CC1234</wd:ID>
                            </wd:Costing_Override_Worktag_Reference>
                            <wd:Costing_Override_Worktag_Reference wd:Descriptor="FD89 XXXXX YYYYY">
                                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">WIDXXXXX</wd:ID>
                                <wd:ID wd:type="Fund_ID">FD89</wd:ID>
                            </wd:Costing_Override_Worktag_Reference>
                            <wd:Costing_Override_Worktag_Reference wd:Descriptor="PJ122201 XXXXX YYYYY">
                                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">WIDXXXXX</wd:ID>
                                <wd:ID wd:type="Project_ID">PJ122201</wd:ID>
                            </wd:Costing_Override_Worktag_Reference>
                            <wd:Costing_Override_Worktag_Reference wd:Descriptor="PG11130 XXXXX YYYYY">
                                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">WIDXXXXX</wd:ID>
                                <wd:ID wd:type="Program_ID">PG11130</wd:ID>
                            </wd:Costing_Override_Worktag_Reference>
                            <wd:Distribution_Percent>0.6</wd:Distribution_Percent>
                        </wd:Worker_Costing_Allocation_Detail_Data>
                    </wd:Worker_Costing_Allocation_Interval_Data>
                    <wd:Worker_Costing_Allocation_Interval_Data>
                        <wd:Costing_Override_ID>COSTING_OVERRIDE-X-YYYY</wd:Costing_Override_ID>
                        <wd:Start_Date>2017-07-01-07:00</wd:Start_Date>
                        <wd:End_Date>2018-06-30-07:00</wd:End_Date>
                        <wd:Worker_Costing_Allocation_Detail_Data>
                            <wd:Order>a</wd:Order>
                            <wd:Costing_Override_Worktag_Reference wd:Descriptor="FD30 XXXXX YYYYY">
                                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">WIDXXXXX</wd:ID>
                                <wd:ID wd:type="Fund_ID">FD30</wd:ID>
                            </wd:Costing_Override_Worktag_Reference>
                            <wd:Costing_Override_Worktag_Reference wd:Descriptor="CC0565 XXXXX YYYYY">
                                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">WIDXXXXX</wd:ID>
                                <wd:ID wd:type="Organization_Reference_ID">CC0565</wd:ID>
                                <wd:ID wd:type="Cost_Center_Reference_ID">CC0565</wd:ID>
                            </wd:Costing_Override_Worktag_Reference>
                            <wd:Costing_Override_Worktag_Reference wd:Descriptor="PG00003 XXXXX YYYYY">
                                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">WIDXXXXX</wd:ID>
                                <wd:ID wd:type="Program_ID">PG00003</wd:ID>
                            </wd:Costing_Override_Worktag_Reference>
                            <wd:Costing_Override_Worktag_Reference wd:Descriptor="UD000004 XXXXX YYYYY">
                                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">WIDXXXXX</wd:ID>
                                <wd:ID wd:type="Organization_Reference_ID">UD000004</wd:ID>
                                <wd:ID wd:type="Custom_Organization_Reference_ID">UD000004</wd:ID>
                            </wd:Costing_Override_Worktag_Reference>
                            <wd:Costing_Override_Worktag_Reference wd:Descriptor="PJ122201 XXXXX YYYYY">
                                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">WIDXXXXX</wd:ID>
                                <wd:ID wd:type="Project_ID">PJ122201</wd:ID>
                            </wd:Costing_Override_Worktag_Reference>
                            <wd:Distribution_Percent>1</wd:Distribution_Percent>
                        </wd:Worker_Costing_Allocation_Detail_Data>
                    </wd:Worker_Costing_Allocation_Interval_Data>
                    <wd:Worker_Costing_Allocation_Interval_Data>
                        <wd:Costing_Override_ID>COSTING_OVERRIDE-X-YYYY</wd:Costing_Override_ID>
                        <wd:Start_Date>2017-01-01-08:00</wd:Start_Date>
                        <wd:End_Date>2017-06-30-07:00</wd:End_Date>
                        <wd:Worker_Costing_Allocation_Detail_Data>
                            <wd:Order>a</wd:Order>
                            <wd:Costing_Override_Worktag_Reference wd:Descriptor="FD30 XXXXX YYYYY">
                                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">WIDXXXXX</wd:ID>
                                <wd:ID wd:type="Fund_ID">FD30</wd:ID>
                            </wd:Costing_Override_Worktag_Reference>
                            <wd:Costing_Override_Worktag_Reference wd:Descriptor="LOA">
                                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">WIDXXXXX</wd:ID>
                                <wd:ID wd:type="Organization_Reference_ID">LOA</wd:ID>
                                <wd:ID wd:type="Custom_Organization_Reference_ID">LOA</wd:ID>
                            </wd:Costing_Override_Worktag_Reference>
                            <wd:Costing_Override_Worktag_Reference wd:Descriptor="CC0565 XXXXX YYYYY">
                                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">WIDXXXXX</wd:ID>
                                <wd:ID wd:type="Organization_Reference_ID">CC0565</wd:ID>
                                <wd:ID wd:type="Cost_Center_Reference_ID">CC0565</wd:ID>
                            </wd:Costing_Override_Worktag_Reference>
                            <wd:Costing_Override_Worktag_Reference wd:Descriptor="PG00003 XXXXX YYYYY">
                                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">WIDXXXXX</wd:ID>
                                <wd:ID wd:type="Program_ID">PG00003</wd:ID>
                            </wd:Costing_Override_Worktag_Reference>
                            <wd:Costing_Override_Worktag_Reference wd:Descriptor="UD000004 XXXXX YYYYY">
                                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">WIDXXXXX</wd:ID>
                                <wd:ID wd:type="Organization_Reference_ID">UD000004</wd:ID>
                                <wd:ID wd:type="Custom_Organization_Reference_ID">UD000004</wd:ID>
                            </wd:Costing_Override_Worktag_Reference>
                            <wd:Costing_Override_Worktag_Reference wd:Descriptor="PJ122201 XXXXX YYYYY">
                                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">WIDXXXXX</wd:ID>
                                <wd:ID wd:type="Project_ID">PJ122201</wd:ID>
                            </wd:Costing_Override_Worktag_Reference>
                            <wd:Distribution_Percent>1</wd:Distribution_Percent>
                        </wd:Worker_Costing_Allocation_Detail_Data>
                    </wd:Worker_Costing_Allocation_Interval_Data>
                </wd:Worker_Costing_Allocations_Data>
            </wd:Response_Data>
        </wd:Get_Worker_Costing_Allocations_Response>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Comment: What is your question? Are you getting an error, or not getting the results you want/expect? Edit your question to explain what is wrong or what you need to know, and include your current and expected results.

Comment: Thanks for responding Alex, Edited my question. with first query i could get the required results but not with second.

Comment: It would still help to show (a) what happens now with your second query, and (b) the output you're trying to get.

Comment: Please include the output result too. It can help others to differentiate between the output results and expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to get data from multiple levels which each have multiple nodes, you can use multiple XMLTable constructs:

```
select x1.employee_id, x1.position_id,
  to_date(x2.start_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24:MI') as start_date,
  x2.order_1, x2.fund_id
from xml_table t
cross join xmltable (
  xmlnamespaces ('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS "env",
      'urn:com.workday/bsvc' as "wd"),
    '/env:Envelope/env:Body/wd:Get_Worker_Costing_Allocations_Response/wd:Response_Data/wd:Worker_Costing_Allocations_Data'
    passing t.raw_xml  
    columns Employee_ID number path 'wd:Worker_Reference/wd:ID[@wd:type="Employee_ID"]',
      Position_ID varchar2(100) path 'wd:Position_Reference/wd:ID[@wd:type="Position_ID"]',
      Interval_Data xmltype path 'wd:Worker_Costing_Allocation_Interval_Data'
) x1
cross join xmltable (
  xmlnamespaces ('urn:com.workday/bsvc' as "wd"),
    '/wd:Worker_Costing_Allocation_Interval_Data/wd:Worker_Costing_Allocation_Detail_Data'
      passing x1.Interval_Data
      columns start_Date varchar2(16) path './../wd:Start_Date',
      order_1 varchar2(20) path 'wd:Order',
      fund_id varchar2(20) path 'wd:Costing_Override_Worktag_Reference/wd:ID[@wd:type="Fund_ID"]' 
) x2
/

EMPLOYEE_ID POSITION_ID START_DATE          ORDER_1 FUND_ID
----------- ----------- ------------------- ------- -------
      11111 P11111      2018-07-01 07:00:00 a       FD89   
      11111 P11111      2018-07-01 07:00:00 b       FD89   
      11111 P11111      2017-07-01 07:00:00 a       FD30   
      11111 P11111      2017-01-01 08:00:00 a       FD30
```

The first XMLTable gets the employee and position IDs, and its own XMLType which is the `Worker_Costing_Allocation_Interval_Data` fragment. The second XMLTable is passed that fragment, and extracts the multiple values at that level. You can go down more levels if you need to.

Notice that the filters for the specific instances of some nodes have changed; rather than using `[2]` to get the second worker reference ID for instance, I've looked for a specific attribute value with `[@wd:type="Employee_ID"]` etc. And a similar construct is sued for the fund ID; your original code was loking for an attribute called `Fund_ID`, not one with that type value.

---

You *can* do it in one level, but the references back up the tree can get a bit confusing. This gets all the fields you want:

```
select x.employee_id, x.position_id,
  to_date(x.start_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24:MI') as start_date,
  to_date(x.end_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24:MI') as end_date,
  x.order_1, x.fund_id, x.project_id, x.program_id, x.Cost_Center_Reference_ID,
  x.custom_organization_ref_id, x.distribution_percent
from xml_table t
cross join xmltable (
  xmlnamespaces ('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS "env",
      'urn:com.workday/bsvc' as "wd"),
    '/env:Envelope/env:Body/wd:Get_Worker_Costing_Allocations_Response/wd:Response_Data/wd:Worker_Costing_Allocations_Data/wd:Worker_Costing_Allocation_Interval_Data/wd:Worker_Costing_Allocation_Detail_Data'
    passing t.raw_xml  
    columns employee_id number path './../../wd:Worker_Reference/wd:ID[@wd:type="Employee_ID"]',
      position_id varchar2(100) path './../../wd:Position_Reference/wd:ID[@wd:type="Position_ID"]',
      start_date varchar2(16) path './../wd:Start_Date',
      end_date varchar2(16) path './../wd:End_Date',
      order_1 varchar2(20) path 'wd:Order',
      fund_id varchar2(20) path 'wd:Costing_Override_Worktag_Reference/wd:ID[@wd:type="Fund_ID"]',
      project_id varchar2(20) path 'wd:Costing_Override_Worktag_Reference/wd:ID[@wd:type="Project_ID"]',
      program_id varchar2(20) path 'wd:Costing_Override_Worktag_Reference/wd:ID[@wd:type="Program_ID"]',
      cost_center_reference_id varchar2(20) path 'wd:Costing_Override_Worktag_Reference/wd:ID[@wd:type="Cost_Center_Reference_ID"]',
      custom_organization_ref_id varchar2(20) path 'wd:Costing_Override_Worktag_Reference/wd:ID[@wd:type="Custom_Organization_Reference_ID" and starts-with(text(), "UD")]/text()',
      distribution_percent number path 'wd:Distribution_Percent'
) x
/

EMPLOYEE_ID POSITION_ID START_DATE          END_DATE            ORDER_1 FUND_ID PROJECT_ID PROGRAM_ID COST_CENTE CUSTOM_ORG DISTRIBUTION_PERCENT
----------- ----------- ------------------- ------------------- ------- ------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- --------------------
      11111 P11111      2018-07-01 07:00:00 2050-06-30 07:00:00 a       FD89    PJ122201   PG11130    CC12340                                0.4
      11111 P11111      2018-07-01 07:00:00 2050-06-30 07:00:00 b       FD89    PJ122201   PG11130    CC1234                                 0.6
      11111 P11111      2017-07-01 07:00:00 2018-06-30 07:00:00 a       FD30    PJ122201   PG00003    CC0565     UD000004                    1.0
      11111 P11111      2017-01-01 08:00:00 2017-06-30 07:00:00 a       FD30    PJ122201   PG00003    CC0565     UD000004                    1.0
```

<strike>I've commented out the `Custom_Organization_Reference_ID`because there are duplicates - LOA and UD000004 - so you'd probably have to go back to multiple XMLTables to handle that anyway.</strike>

This only finds `Custom_Organization_Reference_ID` that start with `UD`, as per your comment.

Comment: Alex, Thank you so much. You are a pro

Comment: Thank you so much Alex, yes I'm still trying to figure out how to handle multiple values for Custom_Organization_Reference_ID

Comment: Quick Question: So can i get only one "Custom_Organization_Reference_ID" which starts with UD?

Comment: @Satish - sure; I've updated to filter the node values using `starts-with`.

Comment: Alex, Thank you so much